# Control a device output volume without setting it as default output device

Tags: macos, audio

Is there any application or command line tool that allows controlling the output volume of each device without setting it as default output device beforehand?

It would be great to be able to control the loudspeaker volume before switching to it.

A while ago i used to use PTHVolume, but it doesn't work on macOS Sierra.
It didn't require to install virtual output devices, it just controlled the volume.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the MIDI utility located in /applications/utilities/ ?

Comment: @Harcker my soundcards do not allow to control both left and right channel at the same time: https://imgur.com/a/ZwfZ4 . In addition, it was very convenient to have it in the menu bar